# Azure AD App privileges for Ansible azure module azure.azcollection.azure_rm_adgroup_info

Tags: linux, bash, azure, ansible, azure-active-directory

I am trying to query all users of an Azure AD group using the Ansible module `azure.azcollection.azure_rm_adgroup_info`. I am Working on Ubuntu / Bash. When logging in from the command line with `az login` I am able to list the users. To automate this I want to use an Azure App. I configured the App credentials in the Ansible module itself and got the error

> msg: failed to get ad group info Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

Which privileges do I need to add to the Azure App to be able to use the `azure_rm_adgroup_info` module? Can the error be caused by something else?

I already added the following privileges:

```
[
  {
    "clientId": "***",
    "consentType": "AllPrincipals",
    "id": "***",
    "principalId": null,
    "resourceId": "***",
    "scope": "profile User.Read Group.Read.All Directory.Read.All openid email"
  }
]
```

Permissions Screenshot:

[image]

My ansible code:

```
- name: Return group
  no_log: '{{ aws_rds_no_log }}'
  delegate_to: localhost
  azure.azcollection.azure_rm_adgroup_info:
    attribute_name: "displayName"
    attribute_value: "{{ group_name | upper }}"
    return_group_members: true
    tenant: "{{ _tennant_id }}"
    subscription_id: "{{ _subscription_id }}"
    client_id: "{{ _client_id }}"
    secret: "{{ _secret }}"
  register: _ad_group
```

Comment: Could you include a full snip of API permissions to know whether they are Application or Delegated permissions? Whether you granted admin consent or not?

Comment: I added the output of "list grants". Is this sufficient?

Comment: I meant full `API permissions` screenshot of your application from Portal like [this](https://i.imgur.com/p7nbC8b.png) and could you include code that you are using too?

Comment: Hi @Sridevi, I've updated the question with a screenshot and my ansible code. In this code snippet I am using variables for tenant, subscription_id, etc. But the result is the same if I directly put it as strings into the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you run **`az login`** command and sign-in as a user, it will use **Delegated** permissions.
> But, if you are authenticating as a service principal by giving Azure App credentials, it will use **Application** permissions.

I registered one Azure AD application and granted same **API permissions** like below:

[image]

When I tried to query all users of an Azure AD group by authenticating as **service principal** with above app credentials, I got **same error** like below:

```
az login --service-principal -u <app-id> -p <client-secret> --tenant <tenant-id>
az ad group member list --group <group-name>
```

**Response:**

[image]

> To **resolve** the error, you need to either grant **`Application`**
> permissions or assign proper **Azure AD directory role** to the
> service principal.

In my case, I assigned **`Directory Reader`** role to the service principal like this:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Roles and administrators -> Select role -> Add assignments*

[image]

After assigning the role, you can find it in **Active assignments** like below:

[image]

When I ran same commands by authenticating as above **service principal**, I got **results** successfully like this:

```
az login --service-principal -u <app-id> -p <client-secret> --tenant <tenant-id>
az ad group member list --group <group-name>
```

**Response:**

[image]

Note that, there will be delay of **`5-10`** minutes after assigning Azure AD directory role to work.

Comment: This seems to be the solution. Unfortunately my company doesn't allow assigning a role without lots of risk checks so I'd prefer to add the Application permissions. Can you tell me exactly which ones those are? My problem is that I have to create a change for each adjustment of the App and it always takes hours up to days.

Comment: The strange thin is that I am able to run the command on the command line like mentioned and the login works and the users of the group are listed, but when I run the ansible script it still says insufficient privileges.

Comment: Did you assign any directory role to that service principal?

Comment: We assigned Directory.Read.All

Comment: I suppose the reason is, that my user has a subscription but the App doesn't